# Cookies in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, calculator

So this code that i have works perfectly and exactly as i want it to. What is does is it takes the input "textmoney" and calculates how much money you make yearly. I have a link to another calculator that makes a more percise prediction. Basically i want to know how to have the website remember what the data input was on "textmoney" on the first page, so that when the user clicks on the more advanced calculator the website will remember the value of "textmoney" and the user won't have to type in the same data again. Do i use cookies?

Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

    var $demo = $('#demo');
    var $textMoney = $('#textmoney');
    var $moneydiv = $('#moneydiv');
    $('#advanced').hide();

    function getmoney(){
        var money = $textMoney.val();
            if (isNaN(money) || money === '') {
                $demo.text('You aint enter no $$$$$$');
            } else {
                var dailyE = $textMoney.val() * 365;
                $demo.text('$' + dailyE + ' per day');
            }
    }

    // on enter key
    $textMoney.keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            getmoney();
            $('#advanced').show();
        } else if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $demo.text('');
            $('#advanced').hide();
        }

    }).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid grey');
    });

    // on click 
    $moneydiv.click(function(){    
        getmoney();
        $('#advanced').show();
    });

});
    </script>
```

Comment: localStorage for modern browsers

Comment: You can use Cookies or local storage in your browser http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: localStorage will be good option  [About LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Another way might be to pass it via the query string?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [HTML5 Web Storate](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp):

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("textmoney", $textMoney.val());

// Retrieve
$textMoney.val(localStorage.getItem("textmoney"));
```

From W3Schools:

> The data in localStorage will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

If you want to store the value just while the browser (or tab) is open. You can use sessionStorage instead:

```
// Store
sessionStorage.setItem("textmoney", $textMoney.val());

// Retrieve
$textMoney.val(sessionStorage.getItem("textmoney"));
```

If your browser desn't support HTML5, cookies are also good idea but be aware that some browsers can also have blocked cookies.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

// Store
setCookie("textmoney", $textMoney.val(), 999999 /* Expiration*/);

// Retrieve
$textMoney.val(getCookie("textmoney"));
```

Comment: localStorage is supported by pretty pretty much all common, modern desktop and mobile browsers, including IE8.